# How to deal with Bitmaps when the activity is in background?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-glide, android-bitmap

I'm in the situation where you have several activities with **different** activities that show **different** images (loaded by Glide usually).

Imagine we mark `.skipMemoryCache(true)`, in an architecture like this:

[image]

By doing this (all activities are stacked and accessible by pressing the back button), I realised the following:

- Phones like OnePlus 3 (2016, 3 years old) wouldn't crash, but it would lead into a high temperature and bad user experience (it lags the render). This was the profile of the OnePlus 3:
  [image]
- Phones like Samsung S4 Mini (2013, 6 years old) wouldn't crash but it would stop loading images.
- Phones like Motorola Moto G (2013, 6 years old and slightly better than the Samsung S4 Mini) would crash after two or three activities with Bitmaps.

Now my question is, according to the guides of how to avoid memory leaks and OOM (Out Of Memory) errors, I wouldn't find something like "don't stack high resources activities". Is this something I'm doing wrong, or should the activities handle something special when `onPause()`?

Comment: How do you "stack" the activites? What's preventing them from being destroyed in the background?

Comment: @Pawel I don't prevent them from being destroyed in the background. Indeed, Android can kill those activities to take more heap, but as you can see in the image, somehow it's storing native data (Bitmaps) and I'm not doing anything at all, it's not releasing itself. It would release if I call finish. Besides, Moto G's phone is crashing.

Comment: Activities are not easy to manage. Have you considered using fragments? With these you would have more controll over the lifecycle.

Comment: @tynn let's say all the images are included in a Fragment, which Fragment is included into an Activity. I prefer not to manage Fragments because they are a big headache to deal with states. Besides, could I do the same thing with Fragments? Could I display 7 fragments of different images and then get back to the original state?

Comment: You could do this. The images should reload whenever you go back. But that's what you need anyhow. Otherwise you'll end up with many bitmaps in memory anyhow. In regards to the fragments you could have a look into Navigation Components. It makes life really easy.

Comment: Android should just destroy those activities if it needs to free memory, and Glide should allow those images to be garbage collected as well. It may be worth adding some logging to the lifecycle callbacks of your activities to verify they aren't being destroyed, and try profiling your app whilst enabling the "Don't Keep Activities" setting in developer options. You aren't retaining views, bitmaps or activities in static references are you? It may be worth sharing some code.

Comment: @PPartisan I can confirm they're not getting destroyed as I can navigate back to them and see the content. I'm not retaining bitmaps or Activities (not even Context) in static references.

Comment: It would be worth seeing some code for a couple of your Activities in that case, to see how you navigate between them (and handle image loading, etc.). It may lead us to a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: This is a general idea anyway. There's nothing more than ImageView.setOnClickListener { goToNextPageWithDifferentImages() }